# If M is $150\%$ of $N$, then $N$ is what percent of $M + N$?

Tags: percentages

My solution was very naive:

Let $N = 100$. Then, $M = 150$. Then, 
$$\frac{N}{N+M}= \frac{100}{100+150}= 0.40$$ which corresponds to $40\%$. Therefore $N$ corresponds to $40\%$ of $M + N$.

I think the solutions is wrong. I need help to find my mistake.
Please help me.

Comment: Why you think its wrong

Comment: It was a MCQ question and there is no 40% in answer

Comment: Is it $66.67%$ of m+n

Comment: @ArchisWelankar  No, it is 40%. See answer below

Comment: Unless, M and N are zero.

Comment: What were the multiple choice options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final answer that $N$ is $40\%$ of $M+N$ is correct.

If the answer was marked wrong, then I can ony imagine it was because you assumed that $N=100$. However this trick will always give the right answer. You could prove it without assuming anything about $N$ in the following manner.

Since $M$ is $150\%$ of $N$ it follows that $M = 1.5N$ so that

$$ \frac{N}{M+N} = \frac{N}{1.5N+N} = \frac{N}{2.5N} = \frac{1}{2.5} = 0.4$$

Comment: Beat me to it. Great illustration.